# File not found error, but I did create a file, I think I had problem with coding

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

So the problem is, I create a fprak.txt on my desktop, and I tried to use the following code to open it, but Error comes out. I use jupyter

**Code:**

```py
file=open('fprak.txt')
print(file)
```

**Error:**

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0d55e3a5adb7> in <module>
----> 1 file=open('fprak.txt')
      2 print(file)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fprak.txt'
```

Comment: Please mention the OS you are using. The location of `Desktop` may change based on that. However, please keep in mind that the present form of the code only looks for the file `fpark.txt` in the same directory from where you launched your Jupyter notebook. So you may have to put the full path of the file. Or copy paste the file at the same location from where you are launching Jupyter.

Comment: Hello, please forgive me. But I don't know how to find the location where I launch my Jupyter....

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```py
file=open('~/Desktop/fprak.txt')
print(file)
```

Note that `print(file)` isn't going to print the file contents. Use `print(file.read())` if you want to print the file contents.